# Execute code once before all Jasmine suites

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am developing a angular application with Agm library to use google maps.
I want to write unit tests many classes : a component displaying a map, a directive using google places API...
For that, in my tests I need to have google maps javascript file loaded.

I have two options, but I can not make any of them work :

1. Use the class `MapsApiLoader` of Agm library, that asynchronously loads the javascript file from google. I need to call this loader once for all tests. I don't know where to place this code. `beforeAll` is executed before all tests of a suite (describe) but I have many classes, so many suites.
2. Have this file loaded by jasmine using a tag  but it does not seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this is to create a [custom Jasmine reporter](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/custom_reporter). This will give you hooks into the jasmine lifecycle.

Your reporter will look something like this:

```
let agmLoader = {
  jasmineStarted(suiteInfo) {
    ...load your stuff...
  };
}
```

As a bonus, if you are using Jasmine 3.0, simply return a `Promise` or mark the function as `async` and the function is asynchronous.

In order to register the reporter, you just do this:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(agmLoader);
```